# how to retain the previously selected radio button in recycler view

Tags: android

[This is what i have achieved by recycler view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vulLw.jpg).I want to keep the previously selected radio button when this activity is launched again.
i achieved it this way.

```
Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    DisputeIssueItem issueItem = issueItems.get(position);
    holder.issue.setText(issueItem.getIssue());
    holder.radioButton.setChecked(position == lastCheckedPosition);
    if(previousLocation != null && position == previousLocation && position != lastCheckedPosition){
        holder.radioButton.setChecked(true);
    }
```

}
but it is selecting the radio button at position 0 and I'm able to select more than one radio button [like here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9369.png) . Please suggest how will i achieve this

Comment: You can use [Shared Preferences](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm) to store selected value then you can use this value in entire application

Comment: I have the value saved but i want to that value to be selected. which I'm not able to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

you should check the radiobutton in the radiogroup like this:
radiogroup.check(IdOfYourButton)

Of course you first have to set an Id to your radiobuttons

or

set radio button true

radio.setChecked(true);

Comment: Im not using radio group, Im using recycler view.